# Is there a common strategy to measure if a difference-significance of two areas under two ROC curves

Tags: classification, statistics, object-detection, matlab, confusion-matrix

I conduct sound detection experiments with mice.
I have a stimulus sound and a "noise" sound that shoukd be ignored.

I want to measure how well the mouse ignors the noise (with respect to, say, ignoring 100% of the noise stimuli).

I have sessions with, say 200 trials of stimulus sound that sould be detected and 40 trials of noise sounds that should be ignored.

I created the confusion matrix and ROC curve (I use Matlab).
Now I want to know how well my mouse is performing compared with "ignoring all noise stims".

Is there a way, or a common used formula, to get a evaluation or a confidence interval of "how good is my ROC AUC comparing to AUC(ROC) = 1"?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your current AUC?

Comment: @BrunoGL, its 0.93352. You are right..  I will add to my questions the confusion matrix and ROC curve. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AUC is a summary statistic of your dataset. As such, if you did the same experiment again you would get a slightly different value - and if repeated several times, you'd get a distribution of values.  You probably want to show that your distribution rarely or never includes 0.5 (indicating random classification). When you have an empirical distribution like this, or a histogram of repeated experiments, you can just count how many of your estimates are $\approx 0.5$.  If none, you're golden.

Since you don't want to do your experiment multiple times, you could 'simulate' that scenario by using samples of your data, but otherwise performing the same process. This is called '[bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics))'.  You can use this method to [construct confidence intervals](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dabestr/vignettes/bootstrap-confidence-intervals.html) around your AUC metric, or equivalently, do a statistical test to see if the metric you get is different from 0.5.

Some [packages](https://rdrr.io/cran/pROC/man/ci.auc.html) have bootstrapped confidence intervals built in to the AUC calculation, so you could just use that.